# Spring form input allowing value attribute

Tags: forms, spring, input

here is my code from jsp page and it is workin fine

```
<form:input  path="version" value="${pcversion}" /> 
<form:input type="hidden" value="${pcplanid}" path="pid"/>
```

does spring form input accept the attributes value and type

Answer (score 0):

Actually the spring form input is redered as a normal form input so it is possible to override some of the attributes of the form tag.

> In Spring MVC, you can use  tag to render a HTML textbox field. For example,

```
<form:input path="userName" />
```

It will renders following HTML code

```
<input id="userName" name="userName" type="text" value=""/>
```

so it will work fine even though the eclipse prediction dosnt show you the tag in it.